# Как сделать чтобы при клике на элементы окна jquery не закрывал его

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link").click(function(){
        $(".elem").toggle();
    });
});
jQuery(function($){
 $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
  var div = $(".link"); // тут указываем ID элемента
  var second = $('.elem');
  var close = $('.close');
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
   second.hide(); // скрываем его
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 1180px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.elem {
 display:none;
 margin-top: 14px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 310px;
 background-color: grey;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.elem:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;

 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid grey;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;

 top: -10px;
 left: 33px;

}
.title {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 position: relative;
}
.link {
 margin-left: 13px;
}
.regions {
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.floating {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 line-height: 0.4;
 width: 20px;

}
a.floating {
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24%;
}
a.floating:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.otherregion {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.edit {
 border:1px solid #9E9E9E;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    height: 23px;
}
form {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.formtext {
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.top {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-right: 38px;
}
.close {
 margin: -27px 0px 20px 444px;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <a class="link" href="#">Науки</a>
 <div class="elem">
  <p class="title">Выберите свой населенный пункт</p><span class="close">X</span>
  <div class="regions"> 
   <a class="floating" href="#">Киев</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Львов</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Полтава</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Днепр</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Одесса</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Николаев</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Харьков</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Запорожье</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Винница</a>
  </div>
  <p class="otherregion">Или выберите другой:</p>
  <form>
   <input class="edit" type="text" name="add" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
  </form>
  <div class="top">Населенный пункт – это город или поселок, в котором находится покупатель. Если он установлен правильно, вы сможете видеть предложения:
  <p class="formtext">  &#8226 всех магазинов, которые производят доставку в ваш город</p>
  <p class="formtext">   &#8226 интернет-магазинов из вашего города.</p></div>
 </div>




</div>
```

Вопрос следующей.Как сделать чтобы при клике на input окно не закрывался + при клике на любое место на окне оно не закрывался и если возможно при клике на икс окно закрывался.Никак не могу решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
    && (second.has(e.target).length == 0 || close.is(e.target))) {
```

Comment: ошибка second is not defined и при клике в другое место в веб странице оно не закрывается

Comment: `var second = $('.elem');` - Ваша строчка? Вставьте мой `if` прямо в Ваш вопрос и попробуйте.

Comment: да .Ето блок который закрывается по нажатию

Comment: Ну что, мне копировать весь Ваш код в ответ, чтобы продемонстрировать, что все работает?

Comment: спасибо вам огромное и прошу прощения я просто неправильно вырезал маленькую часть кода и из за этого не работал так как надо.

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов!